# Unable to get the blobs in a storage account which were created yesterday or before using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage

While I try running the below command

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Blob $BlobName -Container $ContainerName -Context $StorageContext
```

I have the blobs created and present in the Azure storage container with the same name and the access level for the storage container is blob, but still I am not getting the blobs other than the blobs which are created today

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob : Can not find blob 'blablaba.zip' in container 'blabla', or the blob type is unsupported. At C:\GitLocalWorkSpace\blabla.ps1:32 char:1
+ Get-AzureStorageBlob -Blob $BlobName -Container $ContainerName -Conte ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-AzureStorageBlob], ResourceNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ResourceNotFoundException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.GetAzureSto rageBlobCommand
```

Comment: Hi, Jose. The normal storage blob will not appear to you. I guess this storage may not have been created by you? What you may encounter is lifecycle. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Please have a look of the lifecycle management.

[image]

**Original Answer:**

First, please make sure you have already have that blob in the container.(Or to say make sure the blob name is correct.)

Second, please make sure you use the right way.

These command works fine on my side:

First, run below command:

```
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName YourStorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey YourStorageAccountKey
```

replace the **YourStorageAccountName** and the **YourStorageAccountKey** with the below value:

[image]

Second, run this command:

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Blob yourblobname -Container yourcontainername -Context $context
```

Then I can get it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @bowmanZhu,  Actually I had tried the same command itself and 

Also I had created few blobs in the same container just a day before and I was able to see on the same day itself and also able to replace if its on the same day itself. using my powershell commands .

but if I run the same commands on the next day onwards not able to get the blob names 

and if I upload the same blobs again I can see the blobs with the same name multiple times but different upload dates in the azure portal. Also if I try to fetch the blob details on the second day I am not able to get previous blobs

Comment: @JoseMidhun Hi, jose. I notice that you say upload same blob? Do you means snapshot? as far as I know, under the same container we can not create the same blob name.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had found out the Issue,

Even though I was using the commands

Get-AzureStorageBlob my ps script was also using Az commands like Connect-AzAccount

I had replaced all Azure Commands to Az like 
Get-AzStorageBlob instead of Get-AzureStorageBlob

We should be using only single module either Az or Azure or AzureRM thorughout the script else we may get this kind of issues.